# Django Rest Framework parse error in PUT API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF (Django Rest Framework) to develop API's I am getting below error.

> rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting
> value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Everything I have created as per the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Below is my code

```py
def blog_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        single_blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Blog.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if pk:
            serializer = BlogSerializer(single_blog)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    if request.method == "PUT":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = BlogSerializer(single_blog, data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

In the above code, GET is working properly PUT is having some errors.
I'm using Postman to hit API

[image]

Data:

```
{
    "blog_title": "My blog using API",
    "blog_description": "Update: This is a test blog. UPDATED.",
    "blog_user_id": 10,
    "user_name": "admin"
}
```

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#raw-data

Answer (score 2):

Using PostMan, use the `raw` tab, specify you're using `JSON` data, and paste your JSON data. This should do the trick.

[image]